# If a monic polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_{p^k}[X]$, then it is irreducible in $\mathbb Z_p[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $p$ be a prime and $k$ is a positive integer. There is a natural projection of rings $Z_{p^k}[X] \longrightarrow Z_{p}[X]$. Suppose a monic polynomial $f(X) \in Z_{p^k}[X]$. $f(X)$ is called *basic irreducible* if it is irreducible in $Z_p[X]$.

If $f(X)$ is monic basic irreducible, then prove $f(X)$ is also irreducible in $Z_{p^k}[X]$.

I have tried that if $f=gh$ in $Z_{p^k}[X]$, then $f=gh$ in $Z_p[X]$. Without loss of genrality, assume $g=1$ in $Z_p[X]$. Then observing the coefficients, we can deduce that $g=1$ in $Z_{p^k}[X]$.

Comment: Let $\pi$ be the projection. Then $f = gh \in Z_{p^k}[X]$ ($\deg g, \deg h > 0$) would imply that $\pi(f) = \pi(g) \pi(h)$, since $\pi$ is a ring homomorphism. Since $f$ is monic, $\pi(g)$ and $\pi(h)$ would then still have positive degrees (as opposed to what happens with e.g. $g=pX+1$, $h = X+1$), so $\pi(f)$ would be reducible. By the way, the title is still incorrect.

Comment: The OP should clarify what they mean by *irreducible*. Is, for instance, $2X$ reducible modulo 4 or not? The polynomial rings they consider are not integral domains for $k\ge2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}[x]$ let $\overline f$ its reduction in $\mathbb{Z}_{p}[x]$.

Suppose $\overline f$ irreducible and that $f=gh$ where both $g$ and $h$ are non-costant polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}[x]$. Since the reduction map is a ring homomorphism, this means that we must have, say, $\overline h=1$.

But now
$$
\deg f=\deg\overline f=\deg\overline{gh}=\deg\overline g + \deg\overline h=\deg\overline g=\deg g
$$
which is a contradiction.

The above chain of equalities is justified by the facts that reducing a monic polynomial doesn't change its degree, that we may assume $g$ and $h$ monic as well and that the degree of a product of (monic) polynomials is the sum of their degrees.